# BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\Models\Menu::index()

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller

I am getting this error

> Call to undefined method App\Models\Menu::index()

and i don't have any data in my tables yet

Comment: You're going to have to figure out where it's being called, why it's being called, and *if* it needs to be called. You can do `grep -R index * | grep Menu` from your project root to see if you can find it anywhere

Comment: please care to explain

Comment: ```index()``` is not a method on your Menu model therefore it is "undefined". It's going to be a method on your controller. In your case, you might have imported the model instead of controller in your routes/web.php.

Comment: Thank you very much Shawn Lindstrom. Problem fixed

Answer (score 1):

You might import your model instead of your controller in web.php (Route file);

Check the what you use as namespace in web.php and route url
At the top of web.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\MenuController;


Route::resource('menu',MenuController::class);
```